# Как избавиться от ComponentFactoryResolver?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

У меня есть сервис для модального окна и он успешно работает (рендерит компонент ModalComponent в конце тега body). Моя проблема заключается в том, что Angular говорит про ComponentFactoryResolver:

> EN: Angular no longer requires Component factories. Please use other APIs where Component class can be used directly.

> RU: Angular больше не требует фабрик компонентов. Используйте другие API, в которых класс компонента можно использовать напрямую

А я не понимаю, как мне ModalComponent рендерить в конце тега body, без использования ComponentFactoryResolver

```typescript
import { Injectable, ComponentFactoryResolver, ComponentRef, Type, ApplicationRef, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalComponent } from './modal.component';
import { take, timer } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ModalService {
  private modalComponentRef: ComponentRef<ModalComponent> | null = null;

  constructor(
    private readonly componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private readonly appRef: ApplicationRef,
    private readonly injector: Injector
  ) {

    }

  public open(component: Type<any>): void {
    if (this.modalComponentRef === null) {
      const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ModalComponent);

      this.modalComponentRef = componentFactory.create(this.injector);
      this.appRef.attachView(this.modalComponentRef.hostView);
      document.body.appendChild(this.modalComponentRef.location.nativeElement);
    }

    this.modalComponentRef.instance.componentModalContent = component;
    this.modalComponentRef.instance.openModal();
    this.modalComponentRef.instance.close
        .pipe(take(1))
        .subscribe(() => this.close());
  }

  public close(): void {
        if (this.modalComponentRef === null) return;

        const transitionDurationProp = document.documentElement.computedStyleMap().get('--transitionDurationS') as CSSUnitValue;
        const transitionDuration = transitionDurationProp.value || 0.2;

        timer(transitionDuration * 1000)
        .pipe(take(1))
        .subscribe(() => {
            if (this.modalComponentRef === null) return;

            this.modalComponentRef.instance.closeModal();
            this.appRef.detachView(this.modalComponentRef.hostView);
            this.modalComponentRef.destroy();
            this.modalComponentRef = null;
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ты надо использовать ViewContainerRef. Ты можеи предоставить эго в конструкторе следующим образом:

```
construcor(vcr: ViewContainerRef) { }
```

После етого ты можеш использовать его следующим образом:

```
  public open(component: Type<any>): void {
    if (this.modalComponentRef === null) {
      this.modalComponentRef = this.vcr.createComponent(component);
      document.body.appendChild(this.modalComponentRef.location.nativeElement);
    }

    this.modalComponentRef.instance.componentModalContent = component;
    this.modalComponentRef.instance.openModal();
    this.modalComponentRef.instance.close
        .pipe(take(1))
        .subscribe(() => this.close());
```

Comment: Каким образом ViewContainerRef поймёт откуда ему провайдится? Ваш вариант не работает, я его пробовал до написания этого вопроса, ViewContainerRef is not provided, вот файл этот https://github.com/mihinov/youtube-tutorials/blob/master/ng-test-notes/src/app/modules/modal/modal.service.ts
Как я предполагаю, можно было бы как-то с помощью Injector создавать ModalComponent, без фабрики